# HTMLInputElement handle event not getting fired the second time

Tags: html, angular, typescript, onclick, event-handling

```js
  openBrowseDialog(){
    let fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput') as HTMLInputElement;
    if (fileInput) {
      fileInput.accept = '.jpeg, .jpg, .png, .tiff, .pdf'; // Set the allowed file types here 
      fileInput.click();}
  }
  handle(event){
    const files: FileList = event.target.files;
    this.uploadQueue.push(files[0]);
    if(this.uploadQueue.length > 0){
      this.uploadClicked = true;
    }
  }
```

```html
    <p-dialog [closeOnEscape]="false" [resizable]="false" (onHide)="onDialogClose('uploadDialog')" [modal]="true" header="{{isUpload ? lang.Upload : lang.CaptureImage}}" [(visible)]="uploadImageDialog" [style]="{width: 'auto'}">
        <div class="=p-grid">
            <div class="p-col horizontalCenter">
                <p-button [disabled]="cameraClicked" icon="pi pi-plus" label="{{lang.Choose}}" (onClick)="openBrowseDialog(); isUpload = true;">
                    <input id="fileInput" type="file" style="display:none" (change)="handle($event)">
                </p-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p-dialog>
```

I'm opening the p-dialog and clicking the "browsedialog" open button, the handle event is firing for the first time,
but the issue is when I close and reopen the dialog and click on the browse button the "The file handling event" is not fired.